# Gradle error android studio 'AsmBackedClassGenerator'

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am using IntelIJ IDEA with android-studio plugins and Gradle.
I have checkout an old branch and intelIJ said that it required to sync.
That's what I did and an error appeared:

```
...project refresh failed:
Error:Cause: org/gradle/api/internal/AsmBackedClassGenerator
```

Does anyone knows about it ?
I can't see it reported on the web.

more informations here: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/android-studio-sync-failed-error-asmbackgenerator/11082

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I faced some sort of similar sync failure problem. I just found the gradle version used by my android studio, downloaded it and mapped gradle settings to the location of the downloaded zip.

You can download the gradle in the following link.

[Gradle distributions](https://services.gradle.org/)

You can map by `File` > `Settings` > `gradle`.